# What is the proper way to install Python 3.10 or higher on Docker development environments

Tags: python, docker

I use the
`docker/dev-environments-default:stable-1`
as a base image for development environments. However, the OS version (Debian Bullseye) only supports Python versions up to 3.9 via apt, so I can only install newer versions from source.

Are there any other official base images for Docker development environments with a newer OS version that supports the installation of modern Python versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use official docker [Python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python). In the tag you can use the python version you need and they have different OS for the same versions of Python. For example

> python:3.12.1-bookworm
>
> python:3.12.1-bullseye
>
> python:3.12.1-alpine3.19

Comment: But these images don't contain specific parts for developer environments (e.g. git etc.) which dev-environments-default:stable-1 contain

Comment: Well, you could install Python from source, or just create a new image for development using a Dockerfile. You can use the `python:3.12.1-bookworm` image and because its based on debian, you can just do `RUN apt-get install git`. It appears that the docker-dev-environment image hasn't been updated in more than a year. Is there any reason why you would use that image instead of making your own so you can use the tools and versionrs you need?